# Does including multiple particles "break symmetry" here, or is this a mistake?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-states

It is fairly easy to show that the incoherent mixture of 50/50 spin-up vs. down in the z-direction is the same as  50/50 spin-up vs. down in the x-direction (for a spin-1/2 particle). This is encoded in the equality
$$\rho_x = \frac{1}{2}(|{+}\rangle_x\langle{+}|_x +|{-}\rangle_x\langle{-}|_x) = \frac{1}{2}(|{+}\rangle\langle{+}| +|{-}\rangle\langle{-}|) = \rho_z.$$
However, when I do the calculation out for the generalization to two spin-1/2 particles, I find that
$$\rho_x = \frac{1}{2}(|{++}\rangle_x\langle{++}|_x +|{--}\rangle_x\langle{--}|_x) \neq \frac{1}{2}(|{++}\rangle\langle{++}| +|{--}\rangle\langle{--}|) = \rho_z.$$
I expect that this must be a mistake on symmetry grounds, but I've checked it a number of times and can't find my error (the algebra is messy, so perhaps it's there). Do we expect these two state operators to be equal in general?

Comment: Yeah, you have picked the wrong generalization of the incoherent mixture state. It is easy to see you have no weight on the asymmetric cross terms eg $| +- \rangle$.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly those cross terms which don't cancel! Are you saying that I'm correct with the non-equality in the second equation? I guess I wouldn't have expected that a priori. @ComptonScattering

Comment: Yes, those states are not equal. But they are also not the correct generalization of the incoherent mixture state in your first equation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on that front! Would you mind explaining what you mean by "correct"? They seemed to be the natural generalization to me. @ComptonScattering

Comment: In the first case, the sum is over all possible configs of the single spin-$1/2$, i,e, $| +\rangle, | -\rangle$, whereas in the second case you have summed over only two of the four possible configs of two spins $| ++\rangle, | +-\rangle, | -+\rangle, | --\rangle$. Summing over all four will restore the equality.

Comment: To confirm, you are saying $\frac{1}{4}(|{++}\rangle\langle{++}| +|{--}\rangle\langle{--}| + |{+-}\rangle\langle{+-}| +|{-+}\rangle\langle{-+}|)$ is the appropriate generalization? And when we say "appropriate" here, are you meaning this in terms of being the *completely* incoherent state? @ComptonScattering

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thanks again! @ComptonScattering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two particle states are $|J,M\rangle = |1, 1\rangle$ and $|1, -1\rangle $, are both circularly polarized.

Any sum over those won't be rotationally invariant, since it lack $|1, 0\rangle$.

You can work in the $|J, M\rangle $ basis with:

$$ |1, \pm 1\rangle = |\pm\pm\rangle $$
$$ |1, 0\rangle = (|+-\rangle + |-+\rangle)/\sqrt 2$$

$$ |0, 0\rangle = (|+-\rangle - |-+\rangle)/\sqrt 2$$

and then sum over $|J, M\rangle\langle J, M|$ to get a density matrix proportional to $\delta_{jj'}\delta_{mm'}$, which will be isotropic.